# emacs compile-command find makefile in superior directory

Tags: emacs

This seems like such an obvious hack I hate to write it myself, but I've had no luck finding it.

I would like an approach to `M-x compile` that will search upward in the directory tree from *cwd* to the first directory with a Makefile, after which it runs the make command. So, it's basically

1. if ./Makefile exists, run the make command
2. otherwise, `cd ..` and try again

Stop at `$HOME`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code defines `compile-parent`, which locates the nearest `Makefile` and creates a `make` command to use that Makefile.  It behaves like `compile` in that it still prompts, showing you the command that it will use, and giving you a chance to edit it, e.g. by specifying a specific target.

```lisp
(defun compile-parent (command)
  (interactive
   (let* ((make-directory (locate-dominating-file (buffer-file-name)
                                                  "Makefile"))
          (command (concat "make -k -C "
                           (shell-quote-argument make-directory))))
     (list (compilation-read-command command))))
  (compile command))
```

You may also want to look at the [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/) extension, which provides a minor mode to detect projects by the presence of VCS metadata or specific build files, with several commands to work from the project root directory, including a `projectile-compile` command, that runs `M-x compile` from the project root.

Comment: Uagh. `locate-dominating-file` was what I *almost* remembered. Thanks.